# Weblogic is not starting

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I just downloaded `wls1035_dev` zip and set `MW_HOME` and updated `PATH` and I am trying to create a domain

Created a empty directory under wls1035_dev/server. Let it be `dom`.
Then run the following commands as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/overview_domain.html)

```
 java weblogic.Server
```

I  faced a different issue for password and solved it with the help of -D flag for weblogic management.

Then I am getting the following error

```
  illegal state exception : io file not found :
```

File is `weblogicdirectory\wlserver\server\.product.properties`

I couldn't figure out the file in that location also. What file it is? How to create it? Or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some fundamental errors.

You need to create your domain using domain configuration wizard. As explained here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/e14140/newdom.htm

Also you are looking up an outdated documentation for start up command. Check below link out :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13708/overview.htm#START115

Comment: Thanks @ring bearer . I am getting the same error in that mode also.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

**NOTE:**
   I am using `zip` distribution of wls. It's for development purpose. `so It's already installed and used`

So to create those `product properties files`, start `configure.cmd` and then proceed with the `readme.txt` in that zip file.